# Detect if media-content started playing from WKWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, wkwebview

I have a WKWebView and I need to detect if any `media-content(audio/video)` started playing from WKWebView.

I am trying this method:

```
BOOL isOtherAudioPlaying = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] isOtherAudioPlaying];
```

. . . but all time it returns NO.

Comment: please any solution for this help me on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377677/how-to-detect-avplayer-and-get-url-of-current-video-from-wkwebview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a research and the answer is that there is a bug in the simulator and all entire time it will return NO.On the real device it will return YES.

Comment: please any solution for this help me on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377677/how-to-detect-avplayer-and-get-url-of-current-video-from-wkwebview